# Hot reloading with express and chokidar causes a http headers sent error when using multiple routes

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I've been trying a variety of setups for hot reloading and one that I've come across is the https://github.com/glenjamin/ultimate-hot-reloading-example/. Modifying this boilerplate code as a starting point, I've come across the following problem in my server code:

```
// server.js
import chokidar from 'chokidar';
import express from 'express';

const app = express();

// this is the middleware for handline all of my routes
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  require('./server/index')(req, res, next);
  // if I commented out any additional routes, the setup would work fine
  require('./server/foo')(req, res, next);
  require('./server/catch-all')(req, res, next);
});

//this watches the server folder for changes
const watcher = chokidar.watch('./server');

watcher.on('ready', function () {
  watcher.on('all', function () {
    console.log("Clearing /server/ module cache from server");
    Object.keys(require.cache).forEach(function (id) {
      if (/[\/\\]server[\/\\]/.test(id)) delete require.cache[id];
    });
  });
});

app.listen(3000, 'localhost', function (err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  const addr = this.address();
  console.log('Listening at http://%s:%d', addr.address, addr.port);
});
```

The above is the server code that handles clearing the cache by watching for changes with the chokidar module. If I have just one route required inside the app.use middleware function (which listens for every incoming request), I can get it to work. However if have multiple routes, the following error occurs:

Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

This is a common issue posted on stack overflow, but all of the solutions I've come across and attempted haven't worked. My route files are as follows:

```
//index.js
import express from 'express';

const router = express.Router();

router.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
  res.send("greagrehgarhegrehuh").end();
  return next('router');
});

module.exports = router;
//end of index.js

//foo.js
import express from 'express';

const router = express.Router();

router.get('/foo', (req, res, next) => {
  res.send("foo").end();
  return next('router');
});

module.exports = router;
//end of foo.js

//catch-all.js
import express from 'express';

const router = express.Router();

router.get('*', (req, res, next) => {
  res.send("catch all").end();
  return next('router');
});

module.exports = router;
// end of catch-all.js
```

All three routes do the same thing, bar the endpoint. So far I've explicitly called end on each to end the response, used return next('router') to skip the rest of the middleware functions and have also tried doing it without the above as well. Any ideas on what I'm missing here to get this working? Here's a github project that showcases the issue

https://github.com/RonanQuigley/express-chokidar-hot-reload

**UPDATE**

So I actually removed the next calls and seem to have almost got it working by doing the following:

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  require('./server/index')(req, res, next);
  require('./server/foo')(req, res, next);
}); 

// a second app.use middleware, that does the same 
// as the catch all // * router.get from my original post
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  app.get('*', (req, res) => res.send('catch all'));
})
```

However, I can't use this second app.use with another require call to a file with an express router like the others. So it seems that express runs through the middleware stack, reaches the * and tries to set the header twice.

The reason I need the * is normally if a user requests an endpoint that doesn't exist, Node correctly shows up with cannot GET/. However, for some reason, with the setup I've outlined express will then crash. My workaround is using * at the end of the middleware stack and I'd just use a res.redirect to send the user back to wherever, but this causes the above issue I've outlined in my original post. So not sure how to get around that one.

So currently I have either:

1) Hot reloading works without the require for a router.get('*'), but when the user navigates to an endpoint that doesn't exist, express will crash.

2) Hot reloading works with the app.get('*') inside a second app.use call, but I can't then use a router to move this into a separate file.

Comment: Does it work without hot reloading? I am not understanding why you are using next() in you routes?

Comment: See my above update for this; tried to post it as a comment but was too long.

Comment: Have you looked into `express-generator`? You are not using `app.use` correctly and that's why you are running into issues.  `express-generator` will give you a basic setup and understanding of how it works.

Comment: I haven't, but I can look into it. Does it offer hot reloading for the server side?

In what way am I not using app.use correctly?

Comment: No, it doesn't offer or have anything to do with hot reloading. You have a package for hot reloading that works great with express.

Comment: OK, I'll check it out. Though that doesn't answer why I am using app.use incorrectly. My understanding is that the above is a valid way to do it judging by the arg options listed in their docs https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.use

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, so posting this solution up for my own future reference and in case somebody else stumbles into this problem.

After speaking with the express devs, it turns out that this is indeed possible with a combination of the following:

```
// you need to use comma separated routes
app.use(
   dynamic('./server/index'), 
   dynamic('./server/foo')
);

// require the library at runtime and apply the req, res, next arguments
function dynamic(lib) {
  return function (req, res, next) {
    return require(lib).apply(this, arguments)
  }
}
```

In the case of webpack, this would break it as you can't use require as an expression. So use the following to get around that:

```
function createRoutes(router) {
    const dynamic = (lib) => {
        return function (req, res, next) {
            // let webpack generate a regex expression from this require
            // if we don't you would get a critical dependency warning
            // which would result in the routes not being found
            return require("./src/" + lib + ".js").apply(this, arguments);
        }
    }
    router.use(
        dynamic('index'),
        dynamic('foo'),
    );
    return router;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's step back a bit and talk about middleware.

Say you have a function which runs some kind of middleware.

```
const runMiddleware = (req, res, next) => {
  console.log(`this will run everytime a HTTP request comes in`);
}
```

Then to use that middleware within express:

```
app.use(runMiddleware);
```

Every time **any** (GET, POST, DELETE, etc) request comes in, this function is run.

Essentially you are doing the same thing below - You are wrapping three (3) route calls with a **single** function. This function is calling all of these routes at once, hence `res` is actually being sent 3 times in a row in the example below:

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) { // runs every time any request comes in
  require('./server/index')(req, res, next); // res sent, ok
  require('./server/foo')(req, res, next); // res sent, err
  require('./server/catch-all')(req, res, next); // res sent, err
});
```

Here is a basic way of handling routes:

```
const index = require('./server/index');
const foo = require('./server/foo');

app.use('/', index);
app.use('/foo', foo);

// catch everything else
app.use(function (req, res) {
  res.send('catch all');
})
```

Comment: The first one is not sending a response twice as they both handle different routes. It's only when a catch-all i.e * in the same app.use middleware stack that causes that issue.

I've tried the rest of it and this is closer to a solution. However, the foo path would go to foo/foo with that setup, not /foo. I can fix that by just using get('/') in each path's router file. However this doesn't explain why express is not allowing a catch-all route to be defined using a router.